# Transfer game progress between tablets on Plants VS. Zombies FREE?

Tags: android, plants-vs-zombies

I got a new tablet and am trying to figure out how to transfer my progress in Plants VS Zombies FREE from my old one to my new one. There doesn't appear to be an option built in, and I can't find the file location. I am sure someone has asked this, but I couldn't find an answer.

(For clarification, this is *not* the second version)

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Plants Vs Zombies FREE is one of those games where, if you delete the app and reinstall it, you have to start from scratch. (It happened to me personally). There are also no cloud backup options as far as I know. This means that you'll have to look for a way to transfer the data manually.

There is a guide at https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Backup_guide#Android but you may have to root your tablet, thereby voiding your warranty. If you don't know what rooting is, it's basically modifying your phone/tablet system to gain deeper access to more fundamental things, e.g. if you want to overclock CPU, or edit system files. I recommend researching rooting if you don't know about it already, before moving on - it's quite technical. However, it also says that root "may" be needed, so maybe you won't have to.

If the above doesn't work non-root and you're not keen on rooting your tablet, I found this website: https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-game-progress-between-android-devices/ 
The second option recommends an app called Helium which could manually transfer your app's data without root. However, there are almost as many 1-star reviews as 5-stars.

I hope that helps. Things might get a bit technical. Make sure you backup anything important before meddling with the tablet's files. Good Luck!

Comment: I was unable to find the com.popcap folder that the backup guide was talking about. Do you know why this could be? Also, I was able to access the files without rooting the tablet by using android studio.

Comment: Go back to the backup guide. The guide has two sections for android - one is "Backup using data file" and the other is "Backup using data file (For continued free version, root required)". The latter mentions "com.ea.game.pvzfree_row" - different from what you mentioned. "com.popcap" must be for the paid version of the game. Looks like root is the way to go.

Comment: I did find that, but inside the "files" folder, I found two more folders: "al" and "PlantsVsZombies" instead of the user files. "al" contains lots of images, some JavaScript files, and a few other things, but not the user files. "PlantsVsZombies" contains "Xpromo" which contains three folders: "1", "2", "3", all of which include only two image files for each folder. This has left me completely perplexed ... do you have any ideas?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I tried completely copy + pasting the whole com.ea.game.pvzfree_row folder between the tablets, which changed nothing in the slightest.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, try the "al" folder, try searching for "user#_json.dat" or ".user#.dat", "users.dat", or for minigames, "game_###.dat". If it doesn't work, then chances are you might not have permission/access to the files. Are you rooted? There are certain files only available through root, and the article says that it's required. If that doesn't work, then try the Helium app I mentioned earlier. If that still doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas. This may help:  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21112/new-phone-how-to-transfer-game-progress.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Helium claimed that the game didn't allow backups. I am not sure I want to root the device, and didn't find the files (like I mentioned a few comments back, cloning the whole folder didn't do anything). I couldn't find any YouTube videos, so I wonder if it just isn't possible somehow. I will update you if I find a way!

Comment: A final suggestion - look for alternatives to Helium?

Comment: Yah, I did that. The only thing I found was AirDroid, which had the data folder locked. :(

Comment: I believe this link has a way to access the data/data folder files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device